# What if the word I chose doesnt have any embedded vector in pretrained word embedding matrix?

Tags: nlp, cpu-word, word-embedding

Suppose my text corpus includes a rare word which is not present in pre-trained word embedding. How do I tackle this obstacle?

Answer (score 0):

Some solutions that come to mind:

- Define an Unknown Word Vector that is going to represent every word that is not in your list.
- Use n-gram models (Like nearest neighbor)
- Use a different model that explicitly looks at what is inside your words (Like [CWE](https://github.com/Leonard-Xu/CWE))
- Delete these features and focus on features that appear in pre-trained word embedding.
- Semi-supervision learning maybe helpful